# Exercise 5, Section 21 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Let $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$ in the space $\Bbb{R}$. Then $x_n +y_n \to x+y$, $x_n -y_n\to x-y$, $x_n \cdot y_n\to x\cdot y$, and provided that each $y_n\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, $x_n /y_n \to x/y$.

**My attempt:**

**Approach(1):**

> Claim: Assume $X$ is metrizable. $\{a_n \}\to a$ convergence in metric space notion $\iff$ $\{a_n \}\to a$ in topological sense. In other word, $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ $\exists N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $d(a,a_n)\lt \epsilon ,\forall n\geq N$ $\iff$ $\forall U\in \mathcal{N}_a$ $\exists N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_n\in U, \forall n\geq N$.

Proof: ($\Rightarrow$) let $U\in \mathcal{N}_a$. Since $U\in \mathcal{T}_d=\mathcal{T}_X$ And $a\in U$, $\exists \epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B_d(a,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. For $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $d(a,a_n)\lt \epsilon ,\forall n\geq N$. Which implies $a_n\in B_d(a,\epsilon),\forall n\geq N$. Thus $a_n\in U, \forall n\geq N$. ($\Leftarrow$) conversely let $\epsilon \gt 0$. Clearly $B_d(a,\epsilon)\in \mathcal{N}_a$. Then $\exists N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_n\in B_d(a,\epsilon),\forall n\geq N$. Which implies $d(a,a_n)\lt \epsilon, \forall n\geq N$. This completes the proof.

$\Bbb{R}$ is metrizable with euclidean norm. By theorem 3.3 of baby Rudin and above claim, all the sequence given in problem convergence. **Is this proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** (following hint) $\Bbb{R}^2$ equipped with $\mathcal{T}_p$(product topology)=$\mathcal{T}_b$(box topology). By exercise 6 section 19, since $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, we have $x_n \times y_n \to x\times y$. By lemma 21.4 or exercise 12 section 21, $+$, $-$, $\cdot$ and $/$ maps are continuous. By theorem 21.3, $\{f(x_n\times y_n)\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}}\to f(x\times y)$, where $f$ is $+$, $-$, $\cdot$ and $/$ map. **Is this proof correct?**

**Edit:** Domain for $/$ map is $\Bbb{R}\times (\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\} )$ with product topology. Set $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ equipped with subspace topology. So we can apply exercise 6 section 19.

Comment: If what you are trying to prove is blockquoted at the top (algebra of limits in $\mathbb{R}$ basically), then why do you introduce a metrisable space $X$? Are you being asked to prove that they converge in the sense of *topological spaces*?

Comment: @OliverHouse Notion of “convergence” in topological space is different than the notion of convergence in metric space. I proved, under certain condition they are same.

Comment: I know this, I'm just trying to clarify what you are asking, since your blockquoted question at the top does not specify what kind of convergence is being referred to

Comment: @OliverHouse ohhh… I assume topological one.